# MouseMove is not moving the cursor to desired location

Tags: autohotkey

I am working this simple script of copying email from one window, pasting it in second window, submit and then return cursor to the initial position.

This the script I have written.

```
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
coordmode, mouse, screen
setKeyDelay, 200,20
f2::
Send {RButton}
send, e
send, {Enter}
Click 1500, 200
send, ^a
send, ^v
send, {Enter}
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
```

Everything except returning cursor to initial position works fine, the cursors goes to the right bottom of the screen. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`MouseGetPos` is relative to the active window, since it was called before setting the `CoordMode`, but you are using `MouseMove` relative to the screen using those coordinates. Try swapping the first two lines:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
SetKeyDelay, 200, 20
f2::
Send {RButton}
Send, e
Send, {Enter}
Click 1500, 200
Send, ^a
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply I was kinda busy with other projects. This doesnt solve the problem as well. I thought that I should elaborate the problem little better.
There are 2 windows (Win A at left and Win B at right) the script starts with copying stuffs from win A, paste in win B, submits then it should come back to initial position of win A. but it doesn't. I have just tried your version but the cursor stills is relative to win B and goes to right  side of win B

Comment: defined positioning works like `MouseMove, , 438, 383`

Comment: It should return to the position it was in before (unless window A was moved). Try to `WinActivate` win A before moving the mouse.